Why is the ensures clause in my Dafny method for finding the largest monotonic subarray not provable?
I am working on a Dafny program to find the largest monotonic island (strictly increasing or strictly decreasing subarray) in an array. My code defines helper functions to check if a subarray is increasing, decreasing, or all elements are identical, and the main method returns the indices of the largest monotonic subarray.
Here’s the relevant part of my code:
function ValidateInput(A: array?<int>): bool
    reads A
{
    A != null && 1 <= A.Length <= 100
}

function IsIncreasing(A: array?<int>, start: int, end: int): bool
    requires A != null && 0 <= start <= end <= A.Length
    reads A
{
    if start == end then true
    else forall i :: start <= i < end - 1 ==> A[i] < A[i + 1]
}

function IsDecreasing(A: array?<int>, start: int, end: int): bool
    requires A != null && 0 <= start < end <= A.Length
    reads A
{
    forall i :: start <= i < end - 1 ==> A[i] > A[i + 1]
}

function AllElementsIdentical(A: array<int>): bool
    requires A != null && A.Length > 0
    reads A
{
    forall i :: 0 <= i < A.Length ==> A[i] == A[0]
}

method LargestMonotonicIsland(A: array<int>) returns (l: int, r: int)
    requires ValidateInput(A)
    ensures 0 <= l <= r < A.Length
    ensures forall i, j :: (0 <= i <= j < A.Length) &&
        ((IsIncreasing(A, i, j) || IsDecreasing(A, i, j)) ==> 
        (j - i + 1 <= r - l + 1 || (j - i + 1 == r - l + 1 && i >= l)))
{
    if A.Length == 1 || AllElementsIdentical(A) {
        l, r := 0, 0;
        return;
    }

    var maxL := 0;
    var maxR := 0;
    var maxLength := 1;

    var i := 0;
    while i < A.Length
        invariant 0 <= i <= A.Length
        invariant 0 <= maxL <= maxR < A.Length
        invariant maxLength == maxR - maxL + 1
    {
        var j := i + 1;
        while j < A.Length
            invariant i < j && j <= A.Length
        {
            var start := i;
            var end := j - 1;

            if start < end && end < A.Length {
                if IsIncreasing(A, start, end) || IsDecreasing(A, start, end) {
                    j := j + 1;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        var currentLength := j - i;
        if currentLength > maxLength || 
            (currentLength == maxLength && i < maxL) {
            maxL := i;
            maxR := j - 1;
            maxLength := currentLength;
        }

        i := i + 1;
    }

    l := maxL;
    r := maxR;

    // Final Assertions
    assert maxLength == r - l + 1;
    assert maxL == l;
    assert maxR == r;
    assert forall i, j :: (0 <= i <= j < A.Length) &&
        ((IsIncreasing(A, i, j) || IsDecreasing(A, i, j)) ==> 
        (j - i + 1 <= r - l + 1 || (j - i + 1 == r - l + 1 && i >= l)));
}


The ensures clause guarantees:
The indices l and r are valid.
For every monotonic subarray A[i..j], its length is less than or equal to the largest monotonic subarray A[l..r].
In the case of ties, the leftmost subarray is selected.
However, Dafny is unable to prove the ensures clause, particularly for edge cases where:
The array contains identical elements.
The entire array is monotonic
What I Tried:
I added debugging assertions to check the invariants and intermediate values inside the loops:
assert maxLength == maxR - maxL + 1;
assert maxL <= maxR;
assert forall i, j :: (0 <= i <= j < A.Length) &&
    ((IsIncreasing(A, i, j) || IsDecreasing(A, i, j)) ==> 
    (j - i + 1 <= maxLength));


I handled edge cases explicitly by checking if the array is entirely identical or has only one element:
if A.Length == 1 || AllElementsIdentical(A) {
    l, r := 0, 0;
    return;
}


Problem:
Despite these changes, Dafny still cannot prove the ensures clause. I suspect the issue might be related to:
How monotonicity is determined using IsIncreasing and IsDecreasing.
The loop logic for updating maxL, maxR, and maxLength.
Question:
How can I debug or modify my Dafny code to ensure the postcondition is provable for all edge cases? Are there specific techniques or tools to help identify the failing case?

I don't have a full solution for you. You will need to define additional invariants and prove that they are correct and maintained by your loops. Here are some tweaks to your code to get started. It helps Dafny to move complicated expressions into predicates.

    function IsIncreasing(A: array?<int>, start: int, end: int): bool
        requires A != null && 0 <= start <= end < A.Length
        reads A
    {
        if start == end then true
        else forall i :: start <= i < end  ==> A[i] < A[i + 1]
    }

    function IsDecreasing(A: array?<int>, start: int, end: int): bool
        requires A != null && 0 <= start < end < A.Length
        reads A
    {
        forall i :: start <= i < end  ==> A[i] > A[i + 1]
    }
    
    predicate p1(i: int, j: int, r: int, l: int)
    {
        j - i + 1 <= r - l + 1
    }

    predicate p2(i: int, j: int, r: int, l: int)
    {
        j - i + 1 == r - l + 1 && i >= l
    }

    lemma AllElementsIdenticalImpliesNoMonotonic(A: array<int>, r: int, l: int)
        requires ValidateInput(A)
        requires AllElementsIdentical(A)
        requires r == 0 && l == 0
        ensures forall i, j :: (0 <= i <= j < A.Length) && (IsIncreasing(A, i, j) || IsDecreasing(A, i, j)) ==> 
            (p1(i,j,r,l) || p2(i,j,r,l))
    {
        assert r-l + 1 == 1;
        forall i, j | (0 <= i <= j < A.Length) && (IsIncreasing(A, i, j) || IsDecreasing(A, i, j))
            ensures p1(i,j,r,l) || p2(i,j,r,l)
        {
            if IsIncreasing(A, i, j) {
                if i == j {
                    assert A[i] == A[j];
                } else {
                    assert A[i] == A[j];
                    assert 0 <= i  < i+1 <=j;
                    assert forall k :: i <= k < j-1 ==> A[k] == A[i];
                    if i == j-1 {
                        // assert A[i] < A[i+1];
                        assert j-i+1 == 2;
                    }else{

                    assert A[i] < A[i+1];
                    assert false;
                    }
                }
                // assert j - i + 1 <= 1;
            } else if IsDecreasing(A, i, j) {
                // assert j - i + 1 <= 1;
                if i == j {
                    assert A[i] == A[j];
                    assert false;
                } else {
                    assert A[i] == A[j];
                    assert 0 <= i  < i+1 <=j;
                    assert forall k :: i <= k < j-1 ==> A[k] == A[i];
                    if i == j-1 {
                        assert A[i] > A[i+1];
                        assert j-i+1 == 2;
                    }else{
                    assert A[i] > A[i+1];
                    assert false;
                    }
                }
                assert false;
            }

        }
    }


    method LargestMonotonicIsland(A: array<int>) returns (l: int, r: int)
        requires ValidateInput(A)
        ensures 0 <= l <= r < A.Length
        ensures forall i, j :: (0 <= i <= j < A.Length) && (IsIncreasing(A, i, j) || IsDecreasing(A, i, j)) ==> 
            (p1(i,j,r,l) || p2(i,j,r,l))
    {
        if A.Length == 1 || AllElementsIdentical(A) {
            l, r := 0, 0;
            AllElementsIdenticalImpliesNoMonotonic(A, r, l);
            return;
        }

        var maxL := 0;
        var maxR := 0;
        var maxLength := 1;

        var i := 0;
        while i < A.Length
            invariant 0 <= i <= A.Length
            invariant 0 <= maxL <= maxR < A.Length
            invariant maxLength == maxR - maxL + 1
            invariant forall l, k :: (0 <= l <= k < i) && (IsIncreasing(A, l, k) || IsDecreasing(A, l, k)) ==> (p1(l,k,maxR,maxL) || p2(l,k,maxR,maxL))
        {
            var j := i + 1;
            while j < A.Length
                invariant i < j && j <= A.Length
            {
                var start := i;
                var end := j - 1;

                if start < end && end < A.Length {
                    if IsIncreasing(A, start, end) || IsDecreasing(A, start, end) {
                        j := j + 1;
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }

            var currentLength := j - i;
            if currentLength > maxLength || 
                (currentLength == maxLength && i < maxL) {
                maxL := i;
                maxR := j - 1;
                maxLength := currentLength;
            }

            i := i + 1;
        }

        l := maxL;
        r := maxR;

        // Final Assertions
        assert maxLength == r - l + 1;
        assert maxL == l;
        assert maxR == r;
        assert forall i, j :: (0 <= i <= j < A.Length) && (IsIncreasing(A, i, j) || IsDecreasing(A, i, j)) ==> 
            (p1(i,j,r,l) || p2(i,j,r,l));
    }

